# Get Form Action in a Controller

Tags: angularjs

Hello currently I have a html form like that:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" action="/a/url">
     ....
     </form>
     <button ng-click="next(myForm)">Klick me</button>

  </div>
```

is there a way to access the form action ?

Comment: From what I know, no, there is no way. Maybe a findElement is available, but I never heard about that. But, and there is a but, you can look around ng-form, wich allow you to use ng-submit, wich allow you to put your business code into the controller. More important, I think this is the proper angular way to do that.

Comment: You either don't need an action or you don't need Angular :P

Answer (score 0):

what i suggest you not to provide action name in the form, instead of that within ng-click action javascript method in JS file either use $http service or $window service.

This can happen with the following htmlcode:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

     <button ng-click="next(myForm)">Klick me</button>

  </div>
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.next = function (formObject) {
// whatever you want to do
}
```

$scope will pick all the object defined within form tag.
I am also new in ng, if anything wrong here please correct me.